# console is not defined?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I got errors on my extension saying that "console is not defined" as follows

1451925103265   addons.xpi  WARN    Exception running bootstrap method startup on MyExt@foo.net: ReferenceError: console is not defined (chrome://MyExt/content/MyExt.js:353:3) JS Stack trace: MyExt.prototype.register@MyExt.js:353:3 < startup@bootstrap.js:12:5 < XPI_callBootstrapMethod@XPIProvider.jsm:4204:9 < XPI_updateAddonDisabledState@XPIProvider.jsm:4337:1 < AddonWrapper_userDisabledSetter@XPIProvider.jsm:6684:9 < set_userDisabled@extensions.xml:1080:11 < oncommand@about:addons:1:1

What is wrong since console.log works on the startup function in the bootstrap.js file?

BR

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please format error messages either in code format (which preserves line formatting; this is normally preferred), or as quotations. Either format makes the error clearly stand out from the other text in your question.  As it is, it is not easy to tell at a glance what is error text and what is not.

Answer (score 3):

Try importing it like this

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');
```

Comment: There's an `about:config` setting for toggling visibility of console output from extensions, but I don't remember off the top of my head which one it is.  I think `extension` as a search term will narrow it down enough for it to stick out in the list.  Unless they changed something, I don't believe it's necessary to resort to a chrome invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Noitidart's answer gave me a deprecation warning in Firefox 48, because of the 'devtools' component.  This works for me:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://gre/modules/Console.jsm');
```